# Authorization design in Mongoose/Express app

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, authorization

I'm working on an mongoose/express app where the document needs to be loaded from the database before determining whether the user is authorized to perform an action on it. For instance, a user may have `read` privileges for a document, but only if that document has a particular value in its `organizations` field. Or, a user may edit a document, but only if their userid is in an `assignedTo` array in that document.

What are the pros and cons of the following design approaches in a mongoose/express app?

### A: Authorization in middleware, queries database multiple times:

1. User is authenticated in middleware and the user permissions object is grabbed from the user session object.
2. Authorization middleware queries the database for the document that the user is accessing. Based on the user's permissions object and values in the document, it determines whether the user is authorized to perform the action.
3. The route forwards the request to the controller, which loads the mongoose document, performs application logic, updates to the database, and sends the response back to the user.

### B: Authorization in middleware, attaches document to request:

1. User is authenticated in middleware and the user permissions object is grabbed from the user session object.
2. Middleware loads the document from the database and determines whether the user is authorized to perform the action. The middleware then attaches the mongoose document to the request.
3. The route forwards the request to the controller, which performs application logic and updates the database using the mongoose document attached to the request.

### C: Perform authorization in the controller/services layer:

1. User is authenticated in middleware and the permissions object is grabbed from the user session object.
2. The route forwards the request to the controller, which loads the mongoose document from the database, checks whether the user is authorized to perform the action. If so, the controller performs application logic and updates the database.

Approach A fits into the middleware design paradigm but queries the database multiple times. The downsides can potentially be mitigated by indexing the collections with all necessary fields for authorization so that the query is [covered](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query). Approach B seems to violate basic MVC design principle by passing the model through the request. Approach C has neither of the above drawbacks but seems to require more boilerplate code written into the controller/services layer.

I know that there are other potential approaches I haven't considered here as well, especially if you allow for the use of other services like Redis caches.

Comment: We solved this using 'B'. It was the simplest approach. Our middleware looked like `loadDocument, checkPermissions, view`, or `loadDocument, checkPermissions, edit`

Comment: Step one, put the authz in a Service, then you can call the Service from where ever you want - middleware, controller, or some other application accessing your model that doesn't have middleware or controllers.